# what does sql alchemy error f405 refer to?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am running this block of code:

```
database_con = f'mssql://@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}'
engine = create_engine(database_con)
con = engine.connect()

found = tuple(set(df.Type))
diff = 60000 - len(found)
search_number = min(1000, diff)
query = f"""
        select top {search_number} a.Number, c.* from table1 a
        join table2 b on a.number=b.number
        join table3 c on b.id=c.LoanApplicationId
        where c.[Type] in  (59) and a.Number not in {found}
    """
t = pd.Timestamp.now()

data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
```

I used to be able to run this query when the search was 60k, but now am receiving an error https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/errors.html#error-f405 and reading this does not give me insight as to why the query all of a sudden stops working. It also fails when I make the search number of 10k and 5k

I reduced my search number to `10` and it works, but I do not want to keep running this script for ever on such a small amount of data.

Does anyone have any insight why this might fail?

Comment: The linked doc suggests it may be raised by some drivers in the event of a disconnect, which might be possible if the query takes a long time to complete.  Is there any additional error information?  Usually there would be a traceback and (possibly) a more specific error message.

Comment: thanks for that. Unfortunately, there is no further traceback as the terminal output

Comment: What database are you using ?
F405 is the code of a programming error, an error that is usually from another error, raised by the driver.